# how to convert string to IJavaProject type?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am developing a plugin.In this i take project as input from textbox which is a string , but it has to be converted to IJavaProject type before proceeding. How can i do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `projectName` does not exist, `IProject`, which is just a handle, will be null.
`IJavaProject` will also be null... so I would not recommend [beny23](https://stackoverflow.com/users/227140/beny23)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161114/how-to-convert-string-to-ijavaproject-type/2161189#2161189).

The javadoc for `JavaCore.create(IProject)` states, "no check is done at this time on the existence or the java nature of this project".

See [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg75802.html) for creating a Java Project *programmatically* from scratch. Extract

```
final IJavaProject javaProject = JavaCore.create(project);
final IProjectDescription projectDescription =
  workspace.newProjectDescription(projectName);
projectDescription.setLocation(null);
project.create(projectDescription, new SubProgressMonitor(progressMonitor, 1));
```

You can check if is has actually been created with:

```
IJavaProject.getUnderlyingResource().exists();
```

See also [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.jdt/msg08766.html) as another code example of Java Project creation.

[That thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/newsLists/news.eclipse.platform/msg76972.html) also creates project, even though their nature is more complete than just Java.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work

```
IProject project = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProject(projectName);
IJavaProject javaProject = JavaCore.create(project);
```

Comment: Hey beny23....i used that code...but when i use 
javaProject.open(monitor); where monitor is of type IProgressMonitor

its throwing an exception...