# How to open Java project in Eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I used the following code to get `IJavaProject` type from string:

```
IProject project = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProject(projectName);
IJavaProject javaProject = JavaCore.create(project);
```

After this, I used `javaProject.open(monitor);` where monitor is of type `IProgreeMonitor`, to open the project... I am not able  to open the filr there is some problem with it. The exception shown is:

```
Java Model Exception: Java Model Status [com.ibm.plugin does not exist]
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.newJavaModelException(JavaElement.java:501)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Openable.generateInfos(Openable.java:245)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.openWhenClosed(JavaElement.java:514)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getElementInfo(JavaElement.java:251)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Openable.open(Openable.java:431)
 at packagesearch.HelloWorldAction.run(HelloWorldAction.java:49)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:251)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WWinPluginAction.runWithEvent(WWinPluginAction.java:229)
 at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:583)
 at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:500)
 at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$6.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:452)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1003)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3823)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3422)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2384)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2348)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2200)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:495)
 at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:288)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:490)
 at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:113)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:193)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:386)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:549)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:504)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1236)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1212)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161114/how-to-convert-string-to-ijavaproject-type/2161859#2161859), your project does not exist, meaning you are trying to open '`null`'.

Hence the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean [IProgressMonitor](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor.html).

IProgressMonitor is used to get updates on the progress of a task that is running in parallel (i.e. how near to completion it is), not to open resources.

I hope that explains the error, but I'm afraid I don't know how to open the project.